# What operations uses "copy to submatrix" in RcppArmadillo?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo

I'm writing a function using Rcpp and RcppArmadillo and I'm getting the following error:

```
error: copy into submatrix: incompatible matrix dimensions: 1x40 and 40x1
```

What RcppArmadillo operations or function can lead to this error message? I'm having difficulty in tracking what's generating this error.

I'm basically just multiplying matrices by matrices and matrices by matrices rows and columns.

**EDIT**

The function is available at https://github.com/jdanielnd/bfm/blob/master/src/bfm_gibbs.cpp

The x data matrix was generated by the function available at https://github.com/jdanielnd/bfm/blob/master/R/generate_data.r

```
library(Rcpp)
source("generate_data.r")
sourceCpp("bfm_gibbs.cpp")
x <- sample_data()
res <- bfmu_c(x, ite = 100)
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the function producing the error; in particular, something that we could run and reproduce ourselves.

Comment: What about ...  a simple transpose before the copy?

Comment: Hello Dirk! I'm actually trying to understand what's that copy. I believe I'm not extracting any submatrix. Could that be a row or column selection?

Comment: my bet would be on the very last set of lines, where you assign things like `alpha_matrix.row(k) = alpha;`, it sounds like the place where you're attempting to copy *into* a submatrix.

Comment: That's it! Thanks @baptiste.. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll surely accept  it.